# Problem setting up cloud server on Debian 8 for Joomla 3.6.2

Tags: joomla-3.x, apache, hosting, linux

I am trying to migrate joomla site from shared hosing to cloud server on Debian 8. I have installed Apache2, PHP5.6, MySQL and I have Akeeba backup from previous hosting.

After unpacking files to server root, I always get the following error `"Neither your session save path in your server's php.ini not the installation/tmp directory is writeable"`.

After I set 777 to `installation/tmp` installation starts, but at the end of installation it cannot create `configuration.php` file and I have to do it manually. After I do that, site shows up, but then I am presented with another problem - I can't login. Nothing happens after I submit a form.

I guess this has something to do with permissions and session, but since I am really new in this, I have no idea how to solve it. Any help?